# Is ZFC a fragment of this theory?

Tags: set-theory, alternative-set-theories

Let $``\mathcal T x. \phi"$stands for the totality of all objects $x$ satisfying $\phi$. So it is a term of the language as long as $\phi$ has $x$ free and never occur as bound. It cannot be quantified upon, so $\exists \mathcal Tx. \phi, \forall \mathcal Tx. \phi$ are not expressions of the language. Also [existential generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization#:%7E:text=In%20predicate%20logic%2C%20existential%20generalization,generalized%20statement%2C%20or%20existential%20proposition.) doesn't hold over $\mathcal T$ terms, so we do NOT generally have $(\vdash \phi(\mathcal Ty.\phi)) \implies  \vdash \exists x \, (\phi(x))$. Accordingly [universal instantiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_instantiation) does not work as well, so we also do NOT generally have: $(\vdash \forall x (\phi(x))) \implies \vdash \phi(\mathcal Ty. \phi)$. Consider the $\mathcal T$ terms to be objects of a sort other than that of the quantified objects (*sets*). Other than these two exceptions, all the rest of rules of [first order logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) with [equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) are maintanied.

Axioms:

1. **Sets:** $\forall x \, ( x= \mathcal T y. (y \in x))$

*Sets are totalities of their elements.*

2. **Extensionality:** $\mathcal Tx. \phi = \mathcal Tx. \varphi \iff \forall x (\phi \Leftrightarrow \varphi)$

*Totalities of objects satisfying equivalent formulas are identical.*

3. **Comprhension:** $\forall y \, (y \in \mathcal Tx.\phi \iff \phi(y|x))$;

if $y$ does not occur in $\phi$, $x$ only occurs free in $\phi$, and $\phi(y|x)$ obtained by replacing all occurrences $x$ in $\phi$ by $y$.

*An object is an element of the totality of objects satisfying some formula, if and only if, it satisfies that formula.*

4. **Subsets:** $\forall a \, \exists b \, (\cal Tx. (x\in a \land \phi)=b) $

*The totality of all elements of a set satisfying a formula, is a set.*

*Define* $``V_\alpha"$ recusively along the
usual lines.

5. **Hierarchy:** $\forall x \exists \alpha (\lim \, \alpha \land x \in V_\alpha)$

*Every set is an element of some stage of the cumulative hierarchy indexed by a limit ordinal.*

6. **Size:** $\forall \alpha \, ( \bigcup \mathcal Tx. (x=f(\beta) \land \beta \in \alpha) \neq \mathcal Tx. \top  )$

Where $\top$ is any true sentence; and $\bigcup \mathcal Tx. \phi = \mathcal Ty. \exists x \, (\phi(x) \land  y \in x ) $

*The universe is not the union of the image of a set under some function.*

7. **Choice:** $\forall x \, \exists \text { ordinal } \alpha \, \exists  f: x \hookrightarrow  \alpha$

Where $``\hookrightarrow"$ signify "injective function".

*Every set is injective to some ordinal.*

> Can this theory prove all axioms of $\sf ZFC$?

The question is in particular about if this theory can prove all instances of Replacement? Since the other axioms of $\sf ZFC$ are easily provable in this theory.

Comment: It kinda looks like $\cal T$ is a quantifier, but then you write $y\in\mathcal Tx$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, yes it gives this appearance, but with quantifiers the result is not a term, while here the result is a "term", although some higher sort term. The signature of this logic is massive, since it adds a primitive term $\cal Tx.\phi$ for every formula $\phi$ with the required specifications.

Comment: @AsafKaragila $y \in  \cal Tx.\phi$ this must be read as $y \in (\cal Tx.\phi)$, that is $y$ is an element of the object represented by the term symbol $\cal Tx.\phi$. So $\cal Tx.\phi$ denotes the totality of all sets x that satisfy $\phi$, this totality is an "object" of our language, but a kind of a higher sort object.

Comment: For the question to be meaningful, you need to say what a term is, what the logical axioms are, and what the rules of inference are.

Comment: those are the same as for first order logic. The only exceptions I've written above.

Comment: There is not a unique way first order logic can be presented.

Comment: I don't' even see how you get powerset: $\mathcal{T}x.(x\subseteq a)$ gives you the power*class* of $a$, but how do you turn that into a genuine object (e.g. one you can instantiate/generalize over)?

Comment: @NoahSchweber, you get powers from the axiom of Hierarchy. Its built-in that axiom. Any set $x$ is an element of some $V_\alpha$ and thus a subset of it, now take the successor stage and all subsets of that set would be elements of it, and one can easily get power set.

Comment: @NoahSchweber, but also you are right! I've introduced the scheme of subsets to take care of this.